# Image size on tablet, bug or feature

Tags: android-layout

Methodology question. I have an activity with image buttons set in grid.

Every image have different copies placed in separate folders, drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, so on.

I supposed that on tablet it should work out of the box, take image from xxxhdpi, fill the screen. But in reality images look tiny, much blank space.

What I did. I put renamed copy of image from drawable-xxxhdpi to just *drawable* folder. Then I set check if the device is a tablet, then go use this drawable. Now it works fine.

But, it seems to me, again that things should work out of the box. Why so complex? What I`m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`drawable` folder is actually `drawable-mdpi` folder. That is why your image loaded from that folder looks larger, because it has used bigger picture.

`dpi` buckets do not make distinction between screen sizes (tablet, phone) they are used for targeting devices with different dpi's.

If you need larger images for tablets, you just have to add additional larger images, but you should also provide them for all dpi buckets, or make sure that upsampling/downsampling will not damage image appearance if you provide image only for some dpi densities.

You can use following code to inspect your device density bucket:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float density = dm.density; // this will give you device density bucket
```

For 160dpi (mdpi) device density value will be 1.0

You can find more at [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)